# Kafka message aggregate

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, tombstone

I have messages in Kafka topic which is compacted as below

```
1::3$
2::4$
```

Later sometime, some more values has been added to the same keys

```
1::64$
2::145$
```

My desire to achieve from above messages is from a topic as below

```
1::3$,64$
2::4$,145$
```

Any suggestion how to combine the value to the same key in a topic

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're asking here.  Can you be more explicit about the messages that are coming through, and how they're represented in the compacted topic?

Comment: If the topic is compacted, those first messages are gone. In any case, have you tried anything yet? Such as a KTable or regular consumer that stores all the keys and accumulates the values?

Comment: Not yet and in python what are all the options available??

Comment: As mentioned, you can collect all messages in a dictionary or database. When you get a message, check if you've seen the key before, then if so, append the values to old values and update that record... You could practice the same with reading a file, so this problem isn't entirely specific to Kafka

Answer (score 2):

You can use kafka streams to do that:

**Topology:**

**1. Source processor:** Read input topic as KStream

**2. Processor 1:** GroupbyKey() -> produces KGroupedTable, pre req. to aggregate

**3. Processor 2:** Aggregate() -> produces a KTable with combined values like you need. You can materialize the KTable as compacted topic. Then you can read it with a kafka consumer or with interactive queries.